# Remove SpriteVisual previously set by ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual

Tags: uwp, xaml-composition

```
_compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this).Compositor;
_blurSprite = _compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(MainPage.Instance.ContentRoot, _blurSprite);
```

How do I remove `_blurSprite` that has been previsously set byt `ElementCompositionPreview`?

Answer (score 0):

```
ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(MainPage.Instance.ContentRoot, null);
```